# PHP fetch() not returning results for SELECT query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function to search for records by course name:

```
<?php
function searchByCourse()
{
    if (isset($_POST["course_title"])) {
        //Copy to local var
        $course_title = $_POST["course_title"];
        $stmt         = self::$conn->prepare("SELECT student_id, student_name, course_title FROM student_info WHERE course_title = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $course_title);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            $stmt->close();
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            $results_array = array();
            $stmt->bind_result($student_id, $student_name, $course_title_found);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                echo "Fetch! \n";
                $row                 = array();
                $row["student_id"]   = $student_id;
                $row["student_name"] = $student_name;
                $row["course_title"] = $course_title;
                $results_array[]     = $row;
            }
            $stmt->close();
            return $results_array;
        }
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
?>
```

The code seems to execute fine but when I test it using curl for course_title=Computing it should return 3 results. However the `echo "Fetch!"` is never displayed. It seems to be that there is nothing for it to fetch. It's driving me a little crazy. I've checked all the var names in the database and they match up fine. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong here?

EDIT:

This method is part of my class DbHandler. $conn is a protected static MySqli connection object created in `function__contruct()`.

called like this:

```
$db = new DbHandler();
$db->searchByCourse();
```

I have other database functions that work fine for this design pattern. The function is being called correctly. I have also checked the $_POST["course_title"] and that is being passed correctly.

Comment: Thats a function, so where is the code that executes that function and processes its result?

Comment: ...and may be a variable scope issue. Edit: I may be wrong here.

Comment: Is this a class method? You're using `self` but the function is not static.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes sorry it's  class method. $conn is a static var in the class

Comment: Are you instantiating the class, or is this method called statically?

Comment: Have you tested this query outside PHP? Using MySQL Workbench or some other method?

Comment: @Don'tPanic no I haven't. I just tried removing the WHERE course_title = ? and it lists all results as expected, so the code within the fetch() loop works. For some reason using WHERE course_title = someVar isn't working